# Installing osm2pgsql from source not actually installing?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to install osm2pgsql from source on a Mac using Terminal.

I ran these commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git
cd osm2pgsql
./autogen.sh && ./configure && make
```

And it runs, but then if I try to run an osm2pgsql command, it says:

```
-bash: osm2pgsql: command not found
```

There are no further instructions online about how to install from source, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the build-essential and automake packages.
Type the following in the terminal (before trying to install osm2pgsql):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install automake

sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your path! To "install" something is really just to let the OS know where it is, because it's too dumb to figure that out on its own, even if you're in the same directory with it. In Unix, every command is a program; when you enter a command, the OS checks the "path" which is just a list of directories where that command might live.

First of all, to test that it's compiled and working properly in its own directory:

```
./osm2pgsql
```

If that works, add the current directory to the path variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
```

Now you can execute the command from anywhere.